# Solr query filter - check if integer/long field is not present OR if a field is a certain value

Tags: solr

Let's say you have a field in solr:

`myfield_l`

And you want to write a Solr query with a filter query where we want to match:

`long field does not exist`
OR
`long field is 0`

I tried this: `-field_i:[* TO *] OR field_i:0` but it does not work.

Is there some way to do a query like this in Solr?

Comment: `fq=(*:* -field_i:[* TO *]) OR field_i:0`?

Answer (score 0):

Some Solr committers helped me with this. It turns out in my case, this is the simplest query to do what I need:

`String.format("-%s:[%d TO *]", failCountFieldName, maxParseFailures + 1)`

So in my example, this will match both records with no failCountFieldName, or the fail count has not exceeded max parse failures.